# Multiple column matching and adjusting with awk

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
    ID A1 A2 A3
    1  A  G  A
    2  T  G  A
    3  T  A  G
    4  T  G  A
    5  A  A  G
    6  A  C  A
    7  C  T  G
```

which is thousands of rows long and made up of G,C,T,A, where G complements C and A complements T.  What I'm trying to do is to search for a match for A1 in either in A2 or A3. If there is a match then for it to be left as it is and if there isn't to change A2 and A3 to their complements i.e. A=T and G=C and vice versa.

So the output would be:

```
    ID A1 A2 A3
    1  A  G  A
    2  T  C  T
    3  T  T  C
    4  T  C  T
    5  A  A  G
    6  A  C  A
    7  C  A  C
```

I thought I could do it by using awk to filter matching and unmatching IDs using these:

```
   awk '{if($2 != $3 || $2 != $4) print $0}' mergedlist > nonmatchlist
```

and

```
   awk '{if($2 == $3 || $2 == $4) print $0}' mergedlist > matchlist
```

but it only worked for one variable i.e T in the former and A in the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -lane 'sub flip { if ($_[0] eq "T") { "A" } elsif ($_[0] eq "A") { "T" } elsif ($_[0] eq "G") { "C" } elsif ($_[0] eq "C") { "G" } else { $_[0] } } if (!($F[1] eq $F[2] or $F[1] eq $F[3])) { $F[2] = flip($F[2]); $F[3] = flip($F[3]) } print "@F"' < input
```

Should be easy to port back to `awk` as it's not really doing anything fancy, but that would take me more time to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

You could construct an *associative array* as a lookup table for the complements e.g.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    complement["A"]="T"; complement["T"]="A";
    complement["C"]="G"; complement["G"]="C";
  } 

  NR>1 && $3!=$2 && $4!=$2 {
    $3 = complement[$3]; 
    $4 = complement[$4];
  } 

  {
    print;
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to an array as suggested by @steeldriver, you could define a function:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS == " +" }
  NR == 1 {print $0 }
  function CHANGE( F )
    {
      if ( F == "A" ) F = "T"
      else if ( F == "T" ) F = "A"
      else if ( F == "C" ) F = "G"
      else F = "C"
      return F
    }
  NR >= 2 {
    if ( $2 == $3 || $2 == $4 ) print $0
    else {
      $3=CHANGE($3)
      $4=CHANGE($4)
      printf "%5d%3s%3s%3s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4
    }
  }
' file
```